# How to remove columns from a df, if columns are not in df2

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dfs i need to compare, however the way the data was gathered one df has 25 columns and another 20 columns. Keep in mind the column label names are the same (the 20 columns exist in the 25 columns df).

**I can't figure out how to remove columns from df_cont, if they don't exist in df_red + not include columns in df_red, which are not currently df_cont**

```
df_cont     A     B     C     D    E    F
01-01-2019  1     2     3     4    5    5
02-01-2019  1     3     4     4    6    5

df_red      A     B     D     F    G 
01-01-2019  2     5     6     4    3
02-01-2019  2     5     6     4    3
```

Code:

```
df_cont1 = df_cont.query(df_cont.columns == df_red.columns)
```

Expected:

```
df_cont1        A     B     D     F
    01-01-2019  1     2     4     5
    02-01-2019  1     3     4     5
```

Comment: `df_cont = df_cont[df_red.columns]`

Comment: Awesome! I realized what think actually in my dataset. df_red has some columns which don't exist in df_cont, how to deal with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @busybear already stated you can use

```
df_cont = df_cont[df_red.columns]
```

in your special case.

This alternative solution is a bit safer if you don't know which DataFrame is the bigger one:

```
df_cont[df_cont.columns.intersection(df_red.columns)]
```

Comment: Perfect! your alternative solution solves my issue as there are columns in df_red which are not in df_cont